# Kibana user forbidden error {"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk, kibana-7

I just setup my xpack in *elasticsearch 7.1.0* 
as below in elasticsearch.yml:

`xpack.security.enabled: true 
discovery.type: single-node`
in my elasticsearch.yml

Then, i ran
`>elasticsearch-setup-passwords interactive`
and changed all my built-in user passwords.

this is the change i made in *Kibana.yml*

```
xpack.security.enabled: true 
elasticsearch.username: "kibana" 
elasticsearch.password: "password@123"
```

When i restarted Kibana,
i ws prompted with a username password page, where i gave
`kibana/password@123` that i had set in my yml.

Im getting the below response:

```
{"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: can you please tell me about type of security are using

Comment: in elastic search, i set `xpack.security.enabled: true
discovery.type: single-node` @harkeshkumar

Comment: can you tell me what you try to do ________ Just want to use kibana or elastic

Comment: @harkeshkumar, Im trying to enable xpack in elastic stack. I set the changes in xpack in elastic and kibana as ive mentioned in the question (edited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution:
using "elastic" user account instead of kibana fixed this issue.

Comment: means what you did

Comment: there are a lot of built-in users in elasticsearch. you need to use the user "elastic" , as this user has access to kibana. @harkeshkumar

Comment: But the `elastic` user will not be available anymore after having generated the passwords for the built-in users (including `kibana`)...

Comment: This worked for me. The documentation wasn't very clear at all on this.

Answer (score -1):

***Configuring security in Kibana***

To use Kibana with X-Pack security:

Update the following settings in the kibana.yml configuration file:

`elasticsearch.username: "kibana"
elasticsearch.password: "kibanapassword"`

Set the xpack.security.encryptionKey property in the kibana.yml configuration file.

`xpack.security.encryptionKey: "something_at_least_32_characters"`

Optional: Change the default session duration.

`xpack.security.sessionTimeout: 600000`

Restart Kibana.

[Please follow this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/using-kibana-with-security.html) using-kibana-with-security

Comment: if this did same please let me know

Comment: I found the issue to be different. have posted the answer here!